# What is the correct tonguing for this rhythm?

Tags: brass, tonguing

The rhythm is five sixteenth notes in a row, where the first is a pick-up, followed by three eighth notes.  It is an orchestral trombone part.  It must sound percussive.  It's rather fast.  Will this be double-tongued?  A combination of triple and double?

Comment: What's the accent/emphasis pattern on those notes? For example, are the 2nd and 4th 16th notes on the beat? I suspect the accenting pattern will affect how you tongue those notes.

Comment: HOW fast?  CAN you single-tongue it?

Comment: Can you show us the notation? I don't understand your written description.

Answer (score 1):

All depends on the speed.

If you can, I would single tongue as this generally produces a more "percussive" sound.

However, if the speed is too quick for that, try and double tongue.